# Optimality condition for a convex function subject to a unit probability simplex

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

For the optimization problem:
$$\text{minimize}~~f(x)$$
$$\text{subject to}~~x\in{\Delta_n}$$

where ${\Delta_n}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n|\sum_{i=1}^nx_i=1,x\geq0\}$, and $f$ is a proper convex function such that $\text{int}(\text{dom}(f))\cap\text{int}(\Delta_{n})\not=\emptyset$. Also, $f$ is differntibale in its domain.

I wish to know how I can show that $x^*\in{\Delta_n}$ is an optimal solution if and only if there exists $\lambda\in{\mathbb{R}}$ such that for all $i=1,...,n$,
$$\frac{\partial{f(x^*)}}{\partial{x_i}}=\lambda~~\text{if}~~x^*>0~~~\text{and}~~~\frac{\partial{f(x^*)}}{\partial{x_i}}\geq\lambda~~\text{if}~~x^*=0$$.

I tried to approach the problem using KKT conditions, the Projection Theorem, and the optimality principle. Finally, I concluded that I should use the optimality principle.
According to the optimality principle for the case where $x^*=0$, we have $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial{f(x^*)}}{\partial{x_i}}x_i\geq{0}$. Claiming that there exists a $\lambda$ such that $\frac{\partial{f(x^*)}}{\partial{x_i}}\geq\lambda$ seems trivial in this case.

However, I can not reason the case where $x^*>0$. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Update: $x^*$ can not be zero. In the case where $x^*>0$, $\lambda$ turns out to be 0. The optimality condition for the positive orthant can be simplified to $\frac{\partial{f}(x^*)}{\partial{f}(x_i)}.x^*_i=0$. Because $x^*$ can not be zero, we conclude that $\frac{\partial{f}(x^*)}{\partial{f}(x_i)}$ should be zero. This yileds that $\lambda=0$**

Comment: Assuming you are working in $\mathbb{R}^n$, note that the simplex has no interior. Also, if you want to use the derivative, you need stronger assumptions on $f$.

Comment: @copper.hat I added the required assumption on f and fixed the dimension of x. Can you please explain a bit about your hint?

Comment: Your conditions are cumbersome and still preclude the expressions in your answer. Presumably you need $f$ to be differentiable everywhere on $\Delta_n$. The conditions you need to consider are $x^* \in \operatorname{ri} \Delta_n$ or on the relative boundary. Since $0 \notin \Delta_n$ the second condition doesn't make sense.

Comment: Another condition, possibly more appropriate for convex situations, is $x^*$ is optimal **iff** ${\partial f(x^*) \over \partial x} (y-x^*) \ge 0$ for all $y \in \Delta_n$.

Comment: The conditions I mentioned are the same as I have in my problem statement.

Comment: No they are not. $x^*$ can never be zero.

Comment: @copper.hat, Would you mind me asking if you have any comment on the first condition? Any comment on how to prove that? Also, according to the definition of simplex, x can be zero. How would you say $x\not\in\Delta_n$?

Comment: You need to do a little work. If $x \in \Delta_n$ then $\sum_k x_k = 1$ which preludes $x$ being zero.

Comment: @copper.hat. Unfortunately, I’m not completely following.

Comment: If $x=0$ then $x_k = 0$ for all $k$ and you must have $\sum_k x_k = 0$ which is a contradiction.